# Why I can't get currency symbols from its respective Hex/Dec code values (eg: &#8363;) in my web page by default?

Tags: javascript, html, encoding

I'm setting up a new server using node and apollo server and want to support UTF-8 in my web application. Where do I need to set the encoding/charsets ?

I can't get exact symbols from the Hex/Dec symbol code due to lack of Utf-8 support.

```
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
```

Please anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Please post some code! In html, you can set a <meta> tag in the <head>...

Comment: updated the meta tags. please look at it

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “the Hex/Dec symbol code”? Is the document actually encoded in UTF-8? Does the Content-Type HTTP response header that the document’s being served with already specify a charset parameter? (Use the Network pane in browser devtools to check.) If the document’s Content-Type response header specifies a charset parameter, you can’t override that with a meta element in the document — instead you’d need to make the server send with a UTF-8 charset parameter.

Comment: yes, the document which I get from the server is encoded in UTF-8 format. But the header is in the application/JSON format. I had done a try on override response header to UTF-8 format.   **res.setHeader('content-type': 'text/html; utf-8')**. But it defaultly set the content-type to application/json.

Comment: res.setHeader('content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8').

Comment: Thanks guys, Issue fixed! **var symbol = "&#36;"; const parser = new DOMParser();
    return parser.parseFromString(
      `<!doctype html><body>${symbol}`, 'text/html').body.textContent;**